# How to know core data has completed it task swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app. In the home screen(View A) - it fetches the data from network and stores in the local database.

I display the data which has been stored in local in another view(View B).

If user moves to ViewB when the operation of loading data to local still happening in ViewA, it displays nothing. So I want to give some progress bar until the operation is complete. How do I know that operation has been completed? Should I use notification observer or is there any other better way?

If user moves to ViewB after the all data is loaded to local, then there is no problem at all.

Comment: Show code what you have tried.

Comment: For now I'm just fetching data from network and storing it to local, and from viewB I'm fetching data from local and displaying it. But I want to know how to fix the issue, when user moves to viewB when the data is still loading . I want some idea, so that I ca try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, want to know, How you store and fetch data? Put some code, so it's really helpful to fix your issue.

Comment: It's not really a Core Data issue; Core Data is synchronous.  It is your network operation that is asynchronous.  You could post a `Notification` when your network task is complete and observe that notification in ViewB or you could use a `FetchedResultsController` in ViewB, so that as the network task saved elements to Core Data, you would be getting delegate callbacks